Closure of projecting cone is the tangent cone
Let $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set and let $\bar{y} \in Y$.
The tangent cone to $Y$ at $\bar{y}$, denoted $T(Y, \bar{y})$, is the set of all limits of the form $h = \lim t_{l}(y_{l} - \bar{y})$, where $\{t_l\}$ is a sequence of non-negative reals and $\{y_{l}\}$ is a sequence in $Y$ with limit $\bar{y}$. The projecting cone of any set $X$, denoted $P(X)$, is the set of all points $h$ of the form $h = tx$, where $t$ is a non-negative real and $x \in X$.
Let's admit that $T(Y, \bar{y})$ is a convex cone. It is claimed in a paper that $T(Y, \bar{y})$ is the closure of $P(Y - \{\bar{y}\})$, where $Y - \{\bar{y}\} = \{y - \bar{y}: y \in Y\}$. I'm trying to understand why this is so.
In the first place, it is clear that $T(Y, \bar{y})$ is at least a subset of that closure, independently of $Y$'s convexity. Why does the converse inclusion hold?

Proof of $T(Y, \bar{y}) \subseteq \operatorname{cl} P(Y-\{\bar{y}\})$:
If $h \in T(Y, \bar{y})$, then there exists a sequence of nonnegative reals $t_l$ and points $y_l \in Y$ converging to $\bar{y}$ such that $h = \lim_l t_l (y_l - \bar{y})$. Since each $t_l(y_l - \bar{y})$ lies in $P(Y - \{\bar{y}\})$, the limit lies in $\operatorname{cl} P(Y-\{\bar{y}\})$.

Proof of $T(Y, \bar{y}) \supseteq \operatorname{cl} P(Y-\{\bar{y}\})$:
If $h \in \operatorname{cl} P(Y-\{\bar{y}\})$, there exists a sequence of nonnegative reals $t_l$ and points $y_l \in Y$ such that $h = \lim_l t_l (y_l - \bar{y})$. This is almost what we need, except $y_l$ does not necessarily converge to $y$ and readjusting $t_l$ to compensate. We can modify this by "shrinking" $y_l$ toward $\bar{y}$. Concretely, we replace $y_l$ and $t_l$ with
$$\tilde{y}_l := \begin{cases} \bar{y} + \frac{1}{l\|y_l - \bar{y}\|}(y_l - \bar{y}) & \|y_l - \bar{y}\| > 1/l & \\ y_l & \|y_l - \bar{y}\| \le 1/l \end{cases}$$
and
$$\tilde{t}_l := \begin{cases} l\|y_l - \bar{y}\|t_l & \|y_l - \bar{y}\| > 1/l \\ t_l & \|y_l - \bar{y}\| \le 1/l \end{cases}.$$

You can check that $\tilde{y}_l \in Y$ because it lies on the line segment connecting $\bar{y}$ and $y_l$ and because $Y$ is convex.
Moreover, $\|\tilde{y}_l - \bar{y}\| \le 1/l \to 0$ so $\tilde{y}_l \to \bar{y}$.
Finally, $t_l(y_l - \bar{y}) = \tilde{t}_l (\tilde{y}_l - \bar{y})$ for each $l$, so their limits are equal.

